# Microsoft Access Does not return Values

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have written a program to save attendance of employees.The database engine is MS Access. when I execute a query form the C# program using Data-Adapter it does not return values, but when I'm executing the same query in Access it gives results. I have used one table join in the query

---

```
OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(Variables.ConnectionString);
                conn.ConnectionTimeout = 50;
                if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) conn.Open();
                string query = "SELECT l.matchine_number, e.actual_emp_number, e.user_name, e.location_name, l.date_time FROM tbl_log l " +
                               "RIGHT OUTER JOIN tbl_enroled_users AS e ON e.enroled_emp_number = l.enroled_number " +
                               "WHERE " +
                               "l.matchine_number LIKE '*" + txtMatchineNumber.Text + "*' AND " +
                               "e.actual_emp_number LIKE '*" + txtEmpNumber.Text + "*' AND " +
                               "e.user_name LIKE '*" + txtName.Text + "*' AND " +
                               "e.location_name LIKE '*" + txtLocation.Text + "*' AND " +
                               "l.date_time >= #" + dtFrom.Value.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + " 12:00:00 AM# AND " +
                               "l.date_time <= #" + dtTo.Value.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + " 11:59:59 PM# " +
                               "ORDER BY l.matchine_number, e.actual_emp_number, e.user_name, e.location_name, l.date_time";
                OdbcDataAdapter adptr = new OdbcDataAdapter(query, conn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adptr.Fill(dt);               

                if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Close();
```

---

Please Help

Comment: put a breakpoint, debug and copy paste the value of the string _query_ and execute it in access and also add it to your question above editing it. Are you sure about the format: M/d/yyyy ??

Comment: As an aside, be aware that this query is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: OP, please replace that horrible way to open close the connection, it will break at every exception, remove your first and last line and use this: using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(Variables.ConnectionString))
{ //put your other code here... }

Comment: Yes Davide i have done it it is giving results. but not in the program

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the right database?

Comment: Your wildcard character is not correct for ODBC connections. Doesn't really have anything to do with Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without any error-messages or the generated query-string it's just guessing. but my idea is that the wildcards you're using are not correctly interpreted. Try to change * into % and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try first with a simple query like

SELECT l.date_time FROM tbl_log l;

to see if your connection is right, if this works then something is wrong with your query.